# Why I can't get access from a script that is internal?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script with some variables :

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

namespace UnityEditor.TreeViewExamples
{
    [Serializable]
    internal class MyTreeElement : TreeElement
    {
        public float floatValue1, floatValue2, floatValue3;
        public Material material;
        public string text = "";
        public bool enabled;

        public MyTreeElement (string name, int depth, int id) : base (name, depth, id)
        {
            floatValue1 = Random.value;
            floatValue2 = Random.value;
            floatValue3 = Random.value;
            enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to save/load this variables values from this script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public class SaveData
{
    public static void Save()
    {

    }

    public static void Load()
    {

    }
}
```

But when trying to type MyTreeElement in the Save() like this :

```
public static void Save(MyTreeElement)
```

The MyTreeElement is not exist.

Comment: Try giving that parameter *a  name.* `public static void Save(MyTreeElement theTree)`

Comment: @Draco18s Tried it before tried anything I can think of. In the end I found that if I'm moving the SaveData script to the folder in the editor in the Assets of where all the TreeView scripts are it's working fine. First SaveData was in the root Assets folder in the editor now it's in the folder of the treeview scripts and it's working. I can't figure out why is that.

Comment: @Draco18s I'm using unity TreeViewExamples package. And only when moved my script SaveData to the child folder BackendData of the TreeViewExamples it's working I can get access to the variables of MyTreeElement no problems.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. I mean, I understand the concept just fine, but that I don't follow the logic and I have no idea what the TreeViewExamples package is. I suspect (maybe?) there's an assembly definition involved, but without pictures I'm taking shots in the dark.